# Element with z-index is not hiding elements with lower z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

How is this `z-index` formatting supposed to work? I should be able to see only the layer with `z-index` with `150` and not any other, but I am able to see all three layers because `z-indez` isn't working. How is it supposed to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>z-index</title>
  <!--Problem is that the z-index is not at all working-->

</head>
<body >
  <!--first div is with highest z-index, it should be on the top layer of the screen-->
  <div  style="  background-color: #000000 ;height:1000px;width:1000px;z-index:150">
    <!--second div is with 100 z-index, it should be on the middle layer of the screen-->
    <div style=" background-color: #d0d4db;height:500px;width:500px;z-index:100;">

      <!--third div is with 50 z-index, it should be on the lowest layer of the screen-->
      <div style=" background-color: #990a0a;height:100px;width:100px;z-index:50;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: can you show more code , what you need exactly ?

Comment: z-index only affects elements that have a position other than static

Comment: z-index does not hide other layers, they will all show. z-index is used to make sure something is at the front (or back)

Answer (score 4):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

**Note:** *z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).*

I think you need to refer this link also

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: This bit me using bootstrap 4 and menu catalog not hiding over a static dropdown.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

z-index will only work together with `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` and `position:fixed`